# ExtJS Store - copy specific fields to store

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, jsonstore, extjs3

I am implementing extjs 3.2.1 with rails 3.x. I have a JsonWriter that writes all the fields in the MySQL database through Json store. Is there a way to replicate the records from one Json Store to the other, with some difference of fields.

This is what i tried:

```
var RecRecordDef = Ext.data.Record.create([
                              {name: 'product_master_id'},
                                {name: 'qty'},
                               {name: 'stock_price'},{name: 'discount_rate'},
                               {name: 'amount'}
        ]);

    salesbtn.on("click",function(){

                for(var cnt=1;cnt<=salestore.getCount();cnt++)
                {
                    var rectmp= salestore.getAt(cnt);

                    var receiptrec= new RecRecordDef({
                      product_master_id:rectmp.get('product_master_id'),

                       qty:rectmp.get('qty'),
                       stock_price:rectmp.get('stock_price'),
                       discount_rate:rectmp.get('discount_rate'),
                       amount:rectmp.get('amount')
                    });
                    recstore.add(receiptrec);

                }
                  recstore.save();

            });
```

where, `var recstore= Ext.StoreMgr.get('ReceiptStore');`

but I am getting the following output on browser's console : 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined**

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must try something like this:

```
Ext.each(salesstore.getRange(), function(item, index, all){
    var receiptrec= new RecRecordDef({
                  product_master_id: item.get('product_master_id'),

                   qty:item.get('qty'),
                   stock_price:item.get('stock_price'),
                   discount_rate:item.get('discount_rate'),
                   amount:item.get('amount')
                });
                recstore.add(receiptrec);
}, this);
recstore.save();
```